# Deleting Builds from Build Queue when Superseded By Newer Patchsets

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have been using Jenkins v1.617 to automatically run validation tests on three hardware platforms. So far, Jenkins has been very well received and I like it a lot.

I have a series of 'builder' jobs which are triggered with the Gerrit trigger plugin (v 2.13.0). I use the Git client plugin (v 1.17.0) to checkout the code and then build it with a script. On successful completion, the 'builder' jobs trigger 'runner' jobs which are tasked with the mechanics of running the code on the hardware, processing the results and posting them to Gerrit.

Each test run takes about 30 minutes on the hardware. During this time, it is very often the case that several newer patch-sets are pushed to Gerrit for a particular commit. So, my question is, Is there any automated way of removing builds from the build queue if a newer patch-set has been triggered?

Apologies if this has been asked before - I've noticed that a few people have worked around this issue by increasing the number of build slaves - however, I am limited by hardware availability and so don't have that option.